# How do I solve the equation $i(iz^3+1)=8+\exp(i\pi/2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Solve the following equation

$$i(iz^3+1)=8+\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

I tried doing it like this, I don't know how to do it further:

\begin{align*}
-z^3=8+\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-i & \Longleftrightarrow
z^3=i-8-i\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z^3=-8
\end{align*}

Can someone help me?

Comment: Now take cube roots...

Comment: More specifically, take both sides to the $\frac{1}{3}$ and use the multi-valued definition of the power function for complex numbers

Comment: @SeanRoberson I was just confused a bit, I wasn't sure if I can take the cubic roots as usual if z is a complex number

Comment: @S.Farr Great, now for the other two roots? Gotta satisfy the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra

Comment: @S.Farr Note that this is only one solution.

Comment: What gives this problem its *flavor* is that the elegant approach requires **flexible** thinking about when to use Cartesian coordinates and when to use Polar coordinates.  At the start of the problem, Cartesian coordinate *thinking* is best, since it streamlines concluding that $z^3 = -8.$  At this point, it's time to *jump ship* away from Cartesian coordinate thinking, and complete the problem via Polar coordinates, using that $e^{(i\theta_1)}\times e^{(i\theta_2)} = e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z = re^{i\theta}$ for real $r, \theta$:

$$z^3 = -8 \to r^3e^{3i\theta} = -8$$

Taking the modulus on both sides gives us

$$r^3 = |-8| \to r = 2$$

Remember this is the only solution for $r$ because $r$ is defined as real, and cube roots are unique in the real numbers.

Now we have

$$8e^{3i\theta} = -8 \to \cos(3\theta) + i\sin(3\theta) = -1$$

So, we have $\cos(3\theta) = -1$ and $3\theta = \pi + 2n\pi$ for some integer $n.$ So, $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{2n\pi}{3}.$

This will give us $3$ unique solutions, as adding $2\pi$ to $\theta$ will yield a conterminal angle. So:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
z_1 = 2e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}} = 2\left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\right] = 1 + i\sqrt{3}\\\\
z_2 = 2e^{i\pi} = -2\\\\
z_3 = 2e^{i\frac{5\pi}{3}} = 2\left[\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right)\right] = 1 - i\sqrt{3}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Notice that we now have three roots for a polynomial of order $3,$ which satisfies the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. Also notice that because all of our coefficients were real, our two solutions with non-zero imaginary parts are conjugates.

An alternative way to formulate this same solution is to simply take both sides to the $\frac{1}{3}$ power and use the multi-valued definition of the power function on the complex numbers. I chose to do it this way because it just seemed a bit clearer, but they're equivalent methods.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is more of a long comment than an answer now, as my method seems to suck. Also, it's not generalisable. I'm abandoning it altogether.

Let $z = x + iy,\quad x,y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then,

$-8 = z^3 = (x+iy)^3 = ... $

Then equate real and imaginary coefficients and solve to find $x$ and $y$.

OK, let's do it.

$$x^3 + 3x^2 (iy) + 3x (iy)^2 + (iy)^3 = -8$$

gives two equations:

$$ x^3-3xy^2 = -8\quad (1) $$

$$ 3x^2y - y^2 = 0\quad (2) $$

$(2)\implies y(3x^2-y) = 0 \implies y = 0$ or $y = 3x^2$.

$y=0$ gives $x=-2.$

$y=3x^2$ gives $27x^5 - x^3 - 8 = 0$,

and this is nontrivial to solve (unless I'm missing something??).

So I agree with the comments: this method sucks.

I have used it before and it worked out. Not here though... Maybe I'm missing something in my above attempt.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not the downvoter, this method is correct but seems a lot harder. For example, let's try it. We have $x^3-3xy^2 = -8$ and $-y^3 + 3x^2y = 0$ I think and you can probably play with the second equation a little, but the first, I don't know, it just looks a little complicated to me, even if it works out. I personally think you should go a little further and see if things work out. The polar form was conceived to get around this kind of a problem, to be fair.

Comment: If I were even more honest, I'd actually like this answer to be completed somehow,, at least to a degree of clarity that shows it can be solved easily, to contrast it with the polar form answer. If things change in this answer for the better I will certainly up vote ,for one!

Comment: On the one hand, no way does your answer deserve to be downvoted, so I upvoted it back.  On the other hand, the whole point of learning that $e^{(i\theta_1)} \times e^{(i\theta_2)} = e^{i(\theta_1 + \theta_2)}$ is to solve equations such as either $z^3 = 1$ or $z^3 = -1$ in a manner much easier than resorting to Cartesian coordinates.  For example, how would you generalize the Cartesian coordinate method to solve $z^{(17)} = 1$?

Comment: Some mathSE reviewers will downvote an alternative method that is inelegant &/or does not generalize well.  Personally, I disagree with this reaction, and would only consider downvoting answers that are inaccurate/invalid.

Comment: @user2661923 I absolutely agree. Everyone benefits from new/alternative methods. Before the edit the answer did not contain enough information. I think that *was* the problem.

Comment: Great , far better I see! +1 Well done @AdamRubinson Thanks so much. Look, your attempt may not work, but it *illustrates the failure of the method that traditionally works*. For that and that alone, a big thanks.

Comment: Yes I've learned that this method isn't helpful in general. I've come across equations like $ax^7 + bx^4 + c = 0$ before, but I don't think you can change them into disguised quadratics, and solving them is non-trivial as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Here it is another approach for the sake of curiosity:

\begin{align*}
z^{3} = -8 & \Longleftrightarrow z^{3} + 8 = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow z^{3} + 2^{3} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (z+2)(z^{2} - 2z + 4) = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (z + 2 = 0)\vee(z^{2} - 2z + 4 = 0)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?